# define a function which will take group of R code as single program

Tags: r

I have sample code which has filters the data from a data frame and remove few columns in data frame and perform join.

sample code looks like this;

```
SBR<-filter(SB,snum==1)
```

where SB is a dataframe from which SBR is created based on snum column value is 1 and SB has 6 columns

```
SBR<-SBR[-c(1,2,4)]
```

in the above code am trying to remove 1,2,4 columns and perform some more filters and join the dataframes.

Comment: I suspect the only way to pass raw R instructions to a function would be by passing it as a character type. Why do you want to do this when you can use the actual R code directly?

Comment: can we pass a dataframe as a argument?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  Perhaps if you give some more background about what you are trying to achieve, you will get a focused answer.

Comment: as of now i would like to filter the data from the data frame and create a new frame and then remove respective columns and combine the data to the existing dataframe

Comment: Here is my task for you: Write an R script which does precisely this, and then come back here to get help converting it into a function.

Comment: @Tim, As suggested by you am able to create a function and pass dataframe to it and execute the code. Sample code is given as an answer. Thank you

Comment: Programming (and problem solving in general) is a bit like swimming in cold water: Hard to get started, but once you start moving it really isn't so bad.

Answer (score 2):

sample code:

```
Fun<-function(a) {
    args = (commandArgs(TRUE))
    a_RW <- filter(a,snum==1)
    a_RW <- a_RW[-c(1,2,4)]
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Fun(dframe)
```